# Error Implementing Google Maps API to Google Glass

Tags: android, google-maps, google-glass, google-gdk

*Note: we are running it on the Glass, not emulating it*

So, the problem arises when I include:

```
<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"/>
```

in the Manifest file. I get the error:

```
Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY
```

So if I remove the line in the manifest, the application will crash upon getting to the map activity which reads:

```
package com.example.mapping;
import android.app.Activity;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.*;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.*;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.os.Build;

public class MapActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);

    // Get a handle to the Map Fragment
    GoogleMap map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.mapView)).getMap();

    LatLng war = new LatLng(-33.867, 151.206);

    map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(war, 13));

    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .title("Mission Drop Zone")
            .snippet("Navigate to Enemy Hideout")
            .position(war));



}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.map, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.mapView) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container,
                false);
        return rootView;
    }
}}
```

Comment: Can you run anything that uses the Google-maps API on that particular Glass at all?

Comment: @AleksanderLidtke Yes, the main maps and directions application uses google maps, but nothing I have load which implements the API has been able to run properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I understand Google Maps requires Google Play Services. At the moment Google Play Services still aren't officially available on Glass. Also another note is that Glass doesn't have an on device GPS, it actually uses the GPS from your phone for high accuracy positioning.

Comment: Thanks. Rather than Maps API I have achieved the same functionality out of the MapQuest SDK and API.